# Live Update Software for Web Pages on Multiple Screens

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I have six devices on/above my desk:

- A 4k TV
- An Ultrawide monitor
- Two laptop computers
- An iPad
- An android phone

All are connected to the internet and browsing mydomain.org/page, an html page that I am editing using one of the laptops, which has a full page of code. When I press a button on my Wacom tablet that I rerouted through Wacom smart actions to run a script, my code is uploaded over FTP to my server. Right now, I have to reload every page on every device to see the updated results. I want to make a javascript to run on my site that has a LiveLoad() global function. When I execute this function from the DevTools command line, the script stores a cookie that the device is a debug device.

All pages with the script will now enable a small icon over the page that when set to 'live,' the script will open a connection through secure web sockets with an update server that stores up to 10 connections (perhaps only from approved IPs, so that only I can use this on my live site), each registered to the page they are browsing. When I update mydomain.org/page or other pages, my script securely opens a connection and POSTs a secret code to the update server, telling it to send a message over web sockets to  all connected debug devices with that page open. On fast internet, this truly will be the ultimate website building setup if I can just overcome this design hurdle.

**What I don't want:**

- Anything more than a single php script for the server-side implementation. Shared hosting. No root access. No Node. No fancy crap. Single PHP files are the only option.
- Bloated javascript addons. Bare minimum code for receiving a single type of message (an update is needed) is all I need. Perhaps later I can make it more robust with a second type of update (a hard update) where a php script processes all the fonts, scripts, images etc on a page and adds a random query string after them to force a hard-reload of all page resources.

How can I achieve this? Where to start with php web sockets? The internet has proven to be a cynical wasteland of bloated php libraries that require installation in a node enviornment to freelancers struggling to make scripts off of the 2013 websockets API documentation, with no good, simple solutions around.

Comment: `Shared hosting. No root access. No Node. No fancy crap. Single PHP files are the only option.`...then you can't use websockets. End of. A websocket server requires a continually running background process to monitor and maintain the connections (whether that's written in node or PHP, the problem is the same). Unless the shared host already provides such a service then you're out of luck, because shared hosting generally doesn't let you run such processes yourself

Comment: P.s. what exactly is the purpose of this massively convoluted (proposed) setup? It appears to be something to do with debugging but it's unclear what the overall purpose is, with the 6 devices on all one desk. Are you trying to do some load testing on your live server or something?

Comment: What you _might_ be able to do is have a Server Sent Events connection open (seeing as it appears you only want one-way traffic from server to client) which will ping a message to the client telling it to update. You can generally achieve SSE without having a background process by looping infinitely in PHP (although it will probably hog threads on your webserver, so if you have limitations on the number of connections through the shared host you might want to check out whether that causes you any issues if up to 6 connections are always open. )